# After yesterdays update Firefox can no longer connect to the Internet (Chromium does)

Tags: firefox, 19.04

I got a new firefox version with the update yesterday. Today I came home from work started by pc and now it no longer connects to the internet, it just goes on loading.

Chromium and all other porgrams still work properly. When i start firefox from command line ony problem seems to be this:

```
[Child 10897, Socket Thread] WARNING: Unable to create pipe named "10897.3.993530248" in server mode error(Die angeforderte Funktion ist nicht implementiert).: file /build/firefox-MhlWie/firefox-67.0+build2/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 210
```

Firefox v67, Ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Solved with a new profile. However this is annoying. The bugs point toward seccomp sandbox violation and WARNING: Unable to create pipe as shown here as well (quite old): https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/787, https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/388

Comment: A few months ago i lost all my passwords now this. *grrrr*

Comment: Please have a look at the duplicate question, **there is a solution that does not require changing your profile**.